# What is the difference between luceneappengine vs search api?

Tags: google-app-engine, lucene

What is the benefit of using luceneappengine over the search api provided by google app engine?

Comment: what's your use-case?

Comment: webcrawler in app engine for a smallish set of sites (less than 1000)

Comment: I'd compare the costs then. Costs for search API can be predicted.

Answer (score 0):

The `luceneappengine` project was born first of all to make easier the migration of an existing application to google app engine, and next to allow you to deploy a standard lucene application in google app engine environment.

The [search api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/) must be your first choice if you are developing a new google app engine application, unless if you think to move your application into another servlet container that will lack of `search api`.

Other considerations can be done on costs: `luceneappengine` uses the default datastore to save index (it means that will use datastore read and write), `search api` has a dedicated cost definition. You can find the cost details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing). Unfortunately it's hard to predict the cost/operations of a `luceneappengine` application because it depends on indexed files (quantity, size, indexed fields etc..).